# Correct usage of ENV in distributed Node system

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, distributed-system

I am building a relatively complex distributed Node system. Let's say there are two processes (node apps), A and B. They are defined in separate projects.

In addition, there are a couple of custom made node modules, being used in both A and B. Let's call them M and N. In addition, M is using N.

How should I correctly handle environment vars?

I guess I should define .env for both main processes (A and B), handle all ENV vars from there and simply pass the needed env vars from there, down to M and N. This way, M and N (and other internal modules) will receive their own ENV vars passed as parameters on creation.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: I would say yes - either the custom made node modules are purely for interal use and they can use `process.env`, or they can be initialized with parameters from A & B which are derived from their environment variables.

Comment: In a monolithic architecture these challenges did not exist. New networks, technologies, user requirements forces us to design distributed systems like your design. #1 Is your question just for your localhost and at libraries level? #2 Are you working with npm modules or A & B are nodejs web apps? #3 How do you plan to deploy your apps in staging or prod environments?  I have an strategy to manage variables in a distributed environments from infrastructure perspective.

Comment: It's a distributed system and A and B can run on different instances (docker, EC2, whatever). Both create and use M and N, which are implemented as NPM modules. I am unsure about whether M and N should have their own .env or should env vars be "injected" on their creation by A or B.

Answer (score 2):

Having modules getting direct access to `process.env` is not a good idea, and modules having their own `.env` file is an even worse idea.

- `.env` files should not be added to source control *(ie git)* because they change with the environment *(`dev`, `prod`, `pre-prod`)* and sometimes contains sensitive information *(like AWS secret keys)*. So that would require you to paste a `.env` file each time you install your `node_modules` making your deployment process more complex.
- The `.env` file loaded inside your module could merge in unexpected ways with the `.env` of your root app *(remember there is only one `process.env`)*.
- Imagine a case where your module would need to behave differently in two parts of your application. How would you override the data loaded via the `.env` file only in one place?

So in my opinion, your guess is correct: don't put `.env` in `node_modules`.

```js
// This is better...
nModule.someMethod(process.env.PARAM1, process.env.PARAM2);

// ...than this
process.env.PARAM1 = '';
process.env.PARAM2 = '';

nModule.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounds correct and it should work. When you define `.env` file and use `dotenv` package, you will be able to access all the variables inside `.env` in your code. That means that custom made node modules will also be able to access it, and you don't have to pass them anything (you can access them directly with `process.env.NAME_OF_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`).

**SUMERIZE:** Create `.env` file in both A and B, use `dotenv` package, and then you can access environment variables directly inside the code with `process.env.NAME_OF_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` (in custom node modules also). You can create constructor (for custom modules) in modules A and B, and just pass process.env.ENV_WHATEVER as a parameters. That is even better approach since your custom module's logic will be independent from the rest of the app (it will depend only on the input).

**NOTE:** Don't commit your `.env` to Git since `.env` usually have some confidential information. The best practice is to create a `.gitignore` file and add `.env` in it.

**RECOMMENDATION** You can keep all your `.env` files in one centralized place for better management. You can check some password management tools like https://www.dashlane.com/ or https://www.lastpass.com/.

Comment: Thanks @Nenad. I think that's it more less. I just prefer not to invoke config() directly from the modules, and avoid having process.env.ENV_WHATEVER directly from the modules. I feel it is better to have direct access to process.env from A and B only, pass the ENV_WHATEVER to the modules via constructor and make the modules more isolated and reusable.

Comment: But you can also do that. You can create constructor in modules A and B, and just pass `process.env.ENV_WHATEVER` as a parameters. That is even better approach since your custom module logic will be independent from the rest of the app (it will depend only to input). That is great approach if you ask me. Let me add that to answer also.

Answer (score 1):

I feel strongly that environment variables are reserved for, well, the environment. This to me implies a few things:

- Inside the code, these variables should be global, i.e., accessed only via `process.env`.
- They are not passed down to other modules. Certainly it's a good idea to make dependencies customizable with parameters you can pass to the functions they export. But the environment should not be used for that.
- How you load values into `process.env` is really a question of how you start your programs A and B. I personally prefer systemd services for that which have *excellent* support for defining the runtime environment. The dotenv package seems more like a crutch, but it's fine from the program's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned *complex distributed system*. Distribution can also be associated with a hub / centralized key/variable management system. I'm assuming there are many env variables that are shared across your multiple apps.

Isn't it a plus if you create a centralized node that contain all your required variables and protected them with authentication?

All nodes (regardless of app) to maintain only a single password string in order to authenticated with the centralized node, and load all required variables from a single .env file.

Alternatively you can use a system like [vault](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-vault)